# Installing Nginx which port it runs

Tags: nginx

I've uninstalled Apache by following the instructions from this guide it didn't work.

Also installed nginx. It runs but I don't know on which port.

I followed this guide to install it worked until curl -4 icanhazip.com it gives me an ip.

My questions are:

Should nginx run on port 8080?

Which is the port that nginx runs?

I'm using Ubuntu 20

I am new using this operating system. Please help me or advice me how to install nginx.

image nginx runs
[image: nginx runs.]

**apache still runs why**

[image: apache still runs why]

Answer (score 1):

You are asking several questions.

Should nginx run on port 8080? Answer: There is nothing wrong with port 8080, although it is not the default. Why do you ask, though?

Which is nginx's port? By default, 80 and 443. How did you configure it? You can confirm the port(s) by running the command `ss -nltp | grep nginx` as root.

How to install nginx? This is a strange question. Nginx is running, but you ask how to install it? The answer is `apt install nginx`. To configure it, plenty of instructions are available, for example [official instructions](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-open-source/?_ga=2.252595465.1642317203.1618769710-1189101123.1618334979#prebuilt_ubuntu) or the [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04).

Why is Apache still running? You provide no proof it is running. Nginx can serve Apache's default web page, and vice versa. If it is still running, you launched it and did not stop it.

Finally, to improve your post, please

- [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/645689/edit) it and replace images of text with text. Images are often hard to read, are useless for search engines and their text can't be copied.
- provide details of "this guide", mentioned twice.
- describe how you failed uninstalling Apache.
- clarify what you mean by "it worked until curl -4 icanhazip.com". Do you mean it doesn't work any more? How did you check?

Comment: Yes, the port defaults to 80 on Ubuntu and the (document) root is `/var/www/html`, same as Apache's.